# What is the output of the c program and Why?

Tags: c

IF Address of list= 1000 and assume that the address is increment by 4 bytes then what is the output and why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
    int list[3][4] = {0, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11};
    printf("%d\n",*list);
    printf("%d\n",*(*(list+1)));
    printf("%d\n",*(list+1)+1);
    printf("%d\n",*(*list+1)+1);
    printf("%d\n", *((list+1)+1));
    printf("%d",((list+1)+1));
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You invoke UB when you print an address with `"%d"`. Cast to `void*` and use `"%p"`, eg: `printf("%p\n", (void*)*list);`

Comment: That then requires the coder to *know* which expression is a pointer, and which is an `int`. The problem will be easier if they all converted to array notation. For example, `*(list+1)` is `list[1]`.

Comment: OT (kinda) `10245` is an unlikely address for an `int` (considering alignment issues)...

Comment: ``1000`` is not more likely at all. This looks a lot like a school assignment. Which is ok. But show us your work.

Comment: btw, why don't you just run it?

Comment: Obviously, it won't be worth trying to run as a 64-bit compilation. *"The address is increment by 4 bytes"* and is passed to `%d`.

Comment: Step 1: Fix the incorrect printing of pointers. Step 2: Run the code. Step 3: Try to make sense of the output. Step 4: Ask SO about the result/output you don't understand.

Comment: Hint: `*list` is the same as `list[0]` and `*(list+1)` is the same as `list[1]` and consequently `*(*(list+1))` is the same as `*(list[1])` which is the same as `list[1][0]`

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that `*(list + n)` is the same as `list[n]`, so i would first rewrite the code in a more legible way as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int list[3][4] = {
        { 0, 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4, 5 }, 
        { 6, 7, 8 },
        { 9, 10, 11} };
    printf("%d\n",*list); // -> *(list + 0) -> list[0]. mistake, as list[0] is an array, so you are
                            // passing, indeed, the address of the array
                            // { 0, 1, 2 } so the format specifier is 
                            // actually incorrect.

    printf("%d\n",*(*(list+1))); // -> *(list[1]) -> list[1][0] -> 3
                                 // first element of the second row.

    printf("%d\n",*(list+1)+1); // -> list[1] + 1, this is the address of the
                                // first array (the first row) shifted one
                                // element, so it should be the address of
                                // the second element of the second row.

    printf("%d\n",*(*list+1)+1); // -> *(list[1] + 1) -> list[1][1] -> 4.

    printf("%d\n", *((list+1)+1)); // -> *(list + 1 + 1) -> *(list + 2) -> list[2]
                                   // the address of the third row array

    printf("%d",((list+1)+1)); // again, this is list + 2, the adress of the 
                               // third array.

    return 0;
}
```

When an array appears alone in an expression, the meaning of that is the address of the first element of that array, so it should be interpreted as a pointer to the cell type (in some of the cases here it is itself an array, in others it is just an `int` variable)

In my opinion, the person who has told you to solve this problem is just
confounding you, as he is passing addresses and values together to a `printf()` call, using always the same format specifier (for pointers or addresses, `%p` should be used, instead of `%d`, that requires an integer, and in addition is not convertible into an `int` because they are actually different size in 64bit architectures) IMHO this code is completely incorrect. (you have been suggested to print addresses by casting them to `(void *)` first and using `%p` as format specifier

But it is your homework, and your teacher is in charge here.